# VBA password prompt when closing excel

Tags: excel, vba, com

I have a sheet with a Workbook_Open code loading a userform.
After closing the form and the workbook Excel prompts me for the VBA Project password.
I've found some info on this issue on this pages:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/280454
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/8cb79e54-26ae-487c-8945-69b84b2e4eeb/com-addins-and-vba-password-prompt-bug

But it seems to be a problems with COM add-ins, which I have some.
The problem is that the add-ins are not mine and I can't change or disable them.

Is there any other solution?

Comment: I found, that this can happen whenever the memory is corrupted for some reason - so it is very hard to find the source of the problem: e.g. reading a wrong pointer reference which can easily happen when you use Windows API calls and use the wrong data-type (e.g. Long, LongPtr, ..)

Answer (score 3):

For me, the problem was not some add-ins or unreleased references. It was the Dropbox Badge. As soon as I removed it, the password was not solicited anymore when I closed Excel. To disable Dropbox Badge, open the Dropbox app, go to Settings, then Preferences and in the General Tab select "Never show" under Dropbox Badge. 
I found this solution on the following forum: 
https://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/1100960-ever-annoying-vba-password-prompt-at-close-of-excel-2.html

Comment: I also run into this problem when using the new Google Drive. I close Google Drive then it doesn't happen anymore. Google Drive also cause my workbook to produce an "Out of Memory" error when close. That also went away when I close GD before closing the workbook. "Backup and Sync from Google" doesn't have these problems.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you have hanging pointers to objects.
For every 'Set xyz=' you do in VBA, make sure that you have a corresponding 'Set xyz=Nothing'. 
Similarly for anything pointing to or obtained from COM objects. 
Make sure you close any ADO connections etc. 
Be especially careful to handle all errors so that ALL object variables are set to Nothing before the workbook can close, something along these lines:

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text
Public Sub Refresh()
    On Error GoTo FAIL
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    wb.Activate
    ' do something useful
DONE:
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set wb = Nothing
    Exit Sub
FAIL:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    GoTo DONE
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a number of workbooks that were experiencing the same problem with some users. We went through the process of checking for COM add-ins and various combinations of Windows and Office.

In the end we included the following code as part of the workbook_beforeclose event and the problem was resolved for our users.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

Dim intResponse as Integer

'If the workbook needs to be saved then ask the user if they want to save the workbook, if not then exit without saving
'Need a global boolean to ensure the request to save the workbook is not shown twice
If Not ThisWorkbook.Saved And Not blnStartedClose Then
    blnStartedClose = True
    intResponse = MsgBox("Do you want to Save the this Workbook" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                        "Select 'Yes' to save the workbook" & vbNewLine & _
                        "Select 'No' to close without saving", vbYesNo, "Confirm - Workbook Save?")
    If intResponse = vbYes Then ThisWorkbook.Save
End If

'If the user has clicked on 'No' to save the workbook then reset the "Saved" property to TRUE so that when we exit this routine no attempt to save the workbook is made
ThisWorkbook.Saved = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had some clients have this issue and I finally started getting it after installing BlueBeam Extreme. I unchecked the BluebeamOfficeAddIn in the COM Add-Ins and the password box stopped popping up when closing my .xlsm file. I'm going to do more digging to see if it's my code but I haven't had this issue until now and disabling that addin seemed to help...

Answer (score 0):

I think the password entry window that appears when exiting Excel only occurs on computers with low specifications.

[image]

It can be solved by trying the following.

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
 
 If Workbooks.Count = 1 Then
   Shell "Taskkill.exe /F /T /IM Excel.exe"
 End If
 
End Sub
```